# Change index.html from root directory to subdirectory

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

Right now the index.html of my website is loading from the root directory when someone enters www.mydomain.com in their browser, which as I understand it is the default behavior.  I want to move all of my website files into a subdirectory (e.g. public) so that when someone loads www.mydomain.com, the index.html file it loads is in the /public/ directory on my server.  However, I do not want the URL to change to www.mydomain.com/public.  From there, if a link is clicked/, all of the files will be in the public directory.  How would I go about achieving something like that

Comment: What's the point of having a root directory that isn't a root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*) public/$1 [L,NC]
```